# Unable to Upload files in Amazon S3 in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am a beginner using S3 and I want to use it to store certain files of my computer. I wrote a small program in Java that uploads all my files and folders but I have this exception :

```
    Infos: Received error response: Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: F75DC5496B071F7D, AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., S3 Extended Request ID: XtRqjEuUmygswUxFUophRudYKbwi4OY4MK9QnYS4DMrH6JrHZXihUEC4mLZbPqz4
Exception in thread "main" Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: F75DC5496B071F7D, AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., S3 Extended Request ID: XtRqjEuUmygswUxFUophRudYKbwi4OY4MK9QnYS4DMrH6JrHZXihUEC4mLZbPqz4
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:538)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:283)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:168)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2555)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1044)
    at com.socialite.s3export.S3Export.parseDirectory(S3Export.java:89)
    at com.socialite.s3export.S3Export.parseDirectory(S3Export.java:73)
    at com.socialite.s3export.S3Export.parse(S3Export.java:48)
    at com.socialite.s3export.S3Export.main(S3Export.java:122)
```

I am sure I provided the correct credentials to the SDK. I used the same credentials from a previous program for testing purposes and it worked. It's possible for me to create buckets but I am unable to store objects in it. In my code, I use the `PutObjectRequest` to store objects.

Here's how I init my amazon S3 object :

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(
            S3Export.class                      .getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties")));
```

The uploading code :

```
private void parseDirectory(File fin, File fdefault, String out)
            throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("processing .." + fin.getName());

        File[] files = fin.listFiles();

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fdefault);

        for (File f : files) {

            String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            String name = "";

            PutObjectRequest por = null;

            if (f.isDirectory()) {

                name = "d_" + f.getName() + ".properties";

                File metadata = new File(out + name);

                parseDirectory(f, metadata, out);

                pw.println(key + "=" + name);

                //upload to s3
                por = new PutObjectRequest(this.bucketName, key, metadata);

            } else {

                name = f.getName();

                pw.println(key + "=" + name);

                por = new PutObjectRequest(this.bucketName, key, f);

            }


            this.amazonS3.putObject(por);
        }
        pw.close();
    }
```

My code fails in this line : `this.amazonS3.putObject(por);`.

Can somebody explain what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally find the anwer to my question. The truth is in the initialization, I passed a wrong bucket name and I am using a different name for making the requests. That's all.

Comment: Remember that you can always generate a sample project using eclipse aws sdk and see how the interaction with S3, SimpleDB etc works.